# Calling a public function without creating a new object JS

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm playing with JS "oop" (or should i say "pop" - prototype oriented programming?) and tried to do something like static method and functions. I can call function from prototype object but that isn't exactly static function, is it?

I have that code:

```
function a(val){
   this.val = val;
   console.log(this);
   this.foo = function(){
     console.log('hi');
   }
 }
```

And i want to call the foo function without creating a new object. Is something like this is possible? How can i do it?

Comment: Functions are objects too

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to mimic static functions, you'll need to add the methods after you create the "class":

```
function A(val) {
    this.val = val;
}

A.foo = function() {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

Then you can call `A.foo();` without having to use the prototype. It's a lot like the way `Object.keys` works. This makes it a property of the function, rather than a property of the instance, like static functions.

Comment: I think this is what @marius-balaj was hinting at.

Comment: Well, that's interesting... It very similar to static function, but but it cannot contain private values which can be changed only by that class. This is the closest solution which i got:
`function a(val){

   this.foo = function(){
     console.log('hi');
   }
 }

a.val = (function() {
  var x = 0;
  
  return {
    inc: function () {
      x++;
    },
    get: function() {
      return x;
    }
  };   
})();

a.val.inc();
a.val.inc();
a.val.inc();
a.val.get();`

Answer (score 0):

As written, you cannot call `foo` without instantiating `a`.

The best you can do is hide the instantiation of the object like so:

```
var a = {
  foo: function() { 
    console.log('hi');
  }
};
```

As regard to simulating static functions, this is the closest you can come:

```
function A(val) {
  this.val = val;
  console.log(this);
}

A.prototype.foo = function() { console.log('hi'); };
```

You do not need to instantiate A to call foo at this point.

```
A.prototype.foo(); // 'hi'
```

Comment: if not in strict mode, you can call `foo()` after calling `a()`; (no need to instanciate a)